# How can I use setOnKeyPressed twice inside the start method in javaFx?

Tags: javafx

I'm trying to use Event Registration Method `setOnKeyPressed` twice inside the `start` method, but the method I invoke first doesn't work.
For example when I run this code and I click on a key from the keyboard `Wow Wow Wow` is not printed! And when I invoke the other method first, and I run the code and I click on the keyboard, also nothing shows up on the Pane but I get `Wow Wow Wow` printed on the console. I don't know why!

Here's the code:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    String sms = "";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Text txt = new Text();
        txt.setLayoutX(30);
        txt.setLayoutY(30);
        pane.getChildren().add(txt);


        pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            System.out.println("Wow Wow Wow");
        });

        pane.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            sms = sms + e.getText();
            txt.setText(sms);
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();

        pane.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: `onKeyPressed` is a property like any other property. If you set it to one thing, and then immediately set it to another thing, its value is the second thing. If you want to add multiple event handlers, use `addEventHandler(...)`

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much guys , I really appreciate it

Comment: Seems the code you have can be in the same `onKeyReleased` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setOnXxx()` are really convenience methods, behind the scenes it uses `addEventHandler(EventType, EventHandler<Event>)` which allows more than one handler per type.

```
addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, evt -> doSomething());
```

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much guys , I really appreciate it